# Lightning data grid break points

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have developed a Lightning component which works well on all screen sizes (phone/ipad/desptop). However, I need to put that component in Salesforce Community (napili template) and the target area i 300px wide. As soon I place the component in the small area, the UI breaks and overlaps instead of stacking vertically.

I tried with the following example as well:

```
    <div class="slds">
    <!--
      The slds-grid class is applied to the container div.
      The slds-wrap class allows us to specify size adjustments on child columns for responsive behavior.
    -->
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <!--
          Each column in the grid is padded using slds-col--padded.
          Should the display size exceed medium (768px), each column will occupy 50% (1-of-2) of the available container space.
        -->
        <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--1-of-2">
            <div class="slds-form-element">
              <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="firstName">First Name</label>
              <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <input id="firstName" class="slds-input" type="text" placeholder="First name goes here..." />
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--1-of-2">
            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <input id="lastName" class="slds-input" type="text" placeholder="Last name goes here..." />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My requirement is to show the mobile UI when container size is small and desktop UI when container is large (regardless of the actual screen size).

Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.